# After deleting wishlist item programmatically from my Api call It is still visible in frontend magento2?

Tags: magento2, wishlist, delete, items

[image]

This is my code:

```
$wishlistIds = $this->_checkoutSession->getWishlistIds();
$wishlist = $this->_wishlist->create()->loadByCustomerId($this->_customerSession->getCustomerId(), true);
$wishlists = $wishlist->getItemCollection()->load();
            foreach ($wishlists as $wishlistItem) {
                if ($wishlistItem->getId() ) {
                    $wishlistItem->delete();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to add  another code `$wishlist->save();`  which will update wishlist completelty.

```
$wishlistIds = $this->_checkoutSession->getWishlistIds();
$wishlist = $this->_wishlist->create()->loadByCustomerId($this->_customerSession->getCustomerId(), true);
$wishlists = $wishlist->getItemCollection()->load();
foreach ($wishlists as $wishlistItem) {
    if ($wishlistItem->getId() ) {
        $wishlistItem->delete();
    }
}
// save wishlist
 $wishlist->save();
```

**Edit**

I Assume that we have written this code at Action.

As per as magento2, the wishlist is **private content of specific to individual users**.So Magento
Use our customer-data JS library to store private data in local storage, invalidate private data using customizable rules, and synchronize data with the backend.

See that magento article
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html

For this,you have to hit your controller using **POST** Request not **GET** request. because of private only update when post request happen

Also You have  to add your action at

Vendor/ModuleName/etc/frontend/section.xml

like

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="{FrontendName}/{Controllername}/{ActionName}">
        <section name="wishlist"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

Comment: I tried that but still it is not going.Also I tries by flushing cache but still it is not going.

Comment: add `$wishlist->save();` after ` $wishlistItem->delete();` check what happen

Comment: Not working , it is still visible

Comment: after run this code  have to tried to flush cache and check  what  happen?

Comment: still not working!!

Comment: I find out why it is visible because it is store in customer section data ,knockout js fetch the value from it.It is fetching value from mage-cache-storage.     How can reset mage cache storage without logout customer.

Comment: Yes, you are right.. it  will take from localstorage

Comment: Sorry to bother you,Can you please tell how I can achieve this using rest Api .Thanks in advance!!!!!!!!